# HTTPError 400 | Google Cloud Platform importing csv to google sql server (cloud sql)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying a simple operation where I import a csv file from my cloud storage bucket into my cloud sql database. However I repeatedly receive the error message `HTTPError 400: Unknown export file type.`.

I am following https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/csv as reference.

What can be wrong?

[image]

The database `Prod` exists as does the `fundamental` table

[image]

The actual `.csv` data I am trying to import

[image]

Comment: are you certain: gs://pmb-storage/fundamental/CH0012221716.csv returns your database?

Comment: I am trying to append the values inside the csv file into the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is currently not a supported file type in Cloud SQL, SQL Server. As stated in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export/importing#gcloud),

> In Cloud SQL, SQL Server currently supports importing databases using SQL and BAK files.

You can do one of the following:

1. Switch database engine to either MySQL or PostgreSQL where CSV files are supported.
2. If the data on your CSV file came from an on-premise SQL Server database table, you can [create an SQL file](https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-backup-a-table-in-sql-server) from it, then use it to import into Cloud SQL, SQL Server.